# Node categories as label, as node or as label and node?

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to decide if i should implement Categories as nodes or labels.
Especially the query to get a count of nodes belonging to a category is not so easy.
Nodes have to be able to belong to more categories !

Categories as labels, variant 1
Keep a list of categories somewhere, then:

```
MATCH a:cat1, b:cat2, c:cat3, ...
```

With a lot of categories i will get a lot of columns .. so that's not really good. Also lot's of preprocessing on the query.
Not even sure if i could get a count easily from that.

Categories as labels, variant 2

```
MATCH n:category <-- the category label is used to limit the amount of nodes
RETURN DISTINCT labels(n), count(*) as count
```

Will return something like:

```
["category","the actual category label"], 2
```

Looks perfect, but this won't work when a node has multiple categories

```
["category","cat1","cat2"], 2 <-- two nodes found with category "cat1" and "cat2"
["category","cat1"], 4 <-- four nodes found with category "cat1"
```

Now i don't know how to get the count per category ...
Maybe something with `extract(..labels()..)` or `filter(..labels()..)` could be able to do it, but i don't know how.

Categories as nodes
Yes this works ... this is pretty straight forwarded. But aren't labels suppose to be THE thing for categorizing nodes? Plus all the extra relationships i would be creating ..

Maybe i should implement it as both labels and nodes?
Then with labels i can get every node with a category fast. And with a node i could get the category count.

I'm still searching for a good perspective on this problem, so i can not give a concrete implementation question yet.

Comment: how many categories? are these nodes gonna be categorised by other categories as well, or is there just one kind of category?

Comment: I have initially just 1 user for my application, 1 user i guess would create about 10-50 categories. The users can define their own categories, so as the userbase grows, so do the categories. It's just one kind of category. Nodes have different kind of ways to group them, but that will be done by attaching them to grouping-nodes. I thought about prefixing labels used for categories with `"cat_"`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My two cents.

For your kind of categories, I would go with a node per category and create a BELONGS_TO relationship from nodes belonging to that category. There are a number of reasons for this preference of mine.

One of the reasons labels were added is that many people were putting a "type" property on nodes. Another way to talk about labels is that they add a little bit of a "schema" to your graph - in the sense that you can categorise nodes.

With the introduction of labels, there's always the risk that they will be abused. It is just an extra tool in a database that is primarily designed for storing graphs. In an extreme case, you could use labels for almost everything, ending up with a store of "tagged" nodes.

Finally, traversing relationships is the fastest thing Neo4j does. We're talking units of microseconds. Don't be afraid adding thousands of relationships to a node. I'd leave labels for developer-defined "schema-like" information.

So in your case of user-added categories, I'd definitely create category nodes and BELONGS_TO relationships, in favour of labelling.

One last thing with a disclaimer that this is a bit of self-marketing. If you get to a point where you have tens of thousands or millions of relationships per node, and all you're after is counting the relationships, it might be a good idea to cache those counts on the nodes as properties. I've developed a module called "[Relationship Count Module](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-relcount)" for the [GraphAware Framework](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-framework), which does exactly that. I've demonstrated in my MSc. thesis, which is gonna be public in a couple of weeks, that the module speeds up count queries for high-degree vertices by several orders of magnitude, for as little as 10-25% write throughput penalty. Let me know if you need more detail about that.

Comment: Thx for the answer, i'll accept because it gives a sufficient explanation of what labels should be used for and what not. I'm on a REST API, is the framework and module available through REST? Perhaps there are additional cypher functions defined by the framework? I would like to know on follow up information.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah the framework can be used from REST and Cypher, because all it does at the moment is writing additional metadata into the graph behind the scenes. These can be read using all the APIs, including Cypher. However, the support could be better and it is on the roadmap. I suggest you start without it and develop your functionality first. When you start measuring and optimising performance, get back to me (anything at graphaware.com). There's a chance that the framework will be able to do much more at that point. Good luck.